# how to do SOAP request in PHP code

Tags: php, soap

My website is written in PHP. How should I write the PHP code to send a SOAP request to another server and parse the response.

The link below is the server who can accept the request.
   http://gisdata.usgs.gov/XMLWebServices2/Elevation_Service.asmx?op=getElevation

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have options.

If it's available on your server, there's a native [SoapClient](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php) extension for php.  You could use that.

Or, you might prefer the [Zend_Soap](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.client.html) library, which is part of the Zend Framework, but can easily be used independently.

There venerable [nuSoap](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/) library is an old standby.